# I18n for wxpython wx.AboutBox

Tags: python, internationalization, wxpython

I am about to make a wxpython programm translatable.
I invoke python gettext with:

```
import gettext
languagelist = [locale.getdefaultlocale()[0], 'en_US']
t = gettext.translation('myProgram', localedir, ['de_DE','en_US'])
_ = t.ugettext
```

This works fine for everything like:

```
self.statusbar.PushStatusText(_('Connecting service ...'))
```

But now there is this wx.AboutBox

```
info = wx.AboutDialogInfo()
info.Name = swname
info.Version = swversion
info.Developers = swdevelopers
info.License = wordwrap(swlicense, 500, wx.ClientDC(self))
wx.AboutBox(info)
```

This AboutBox has buttons labeled "Developers" and "License" and these buttons do not get translated.

No surprise I just ran `pygettext -d myProgram mainFile.py` to create the .pot file.

So how do I get the text from wx.AboutBix into my .pot file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are already translated for you and are contained in the wxstd.pot, respectively in the wxstd.mo of the relevant language.

In the wxPython Phoenix documentation is some more information and a small sample application - http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/internationalization.html?highlight=i18n  this also works for the wxPython Classic, which you probably use.

Comment: Thanks that was it. The points I was missing were setting the locale-property of the app, the wx.Locale.AddCatalogLookupPathPrefix and adding the wxstd.mo to my package.